# Assigning values in a 2D array

Tags: rust

I'm writing some code in Rust (mainly as a POC). The code takes a 2D array, passes it to a second function to do some matrix math (I know there is a standard library to do this, but I want to get used to how things work).

The problem is that the assignment to a 2D array is causing an issue.

My code looks like this

```
fn main() 
{
    // first create a couple of arrays - these will be used
    // for the vectors
    let line1: [i32; 4] = [4, 2, 3, 3];
    let line2: [i32; 4] = [3, 4, 5, 7];
    let line3: [i32; 4] = [2, 9, 6, 2];
    let line4: [i32; 4] = [5, 7, 2, 4];

    // create two holding arrays and assign
    let array_one = [line1, line3, line4, line2];
    let array_two = [line2, line1, line3, line4];

    // let's do the multiply
    let result = matrix_multiply(&array_one, &array_two);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}

fn matrix_multiply(vec1:&[&[i32;4];4], vec2:&[&[i32;4];4]) -> [[i32; 4];4]
{
    // we need to deference the parameters passed in
    let vec_one:[[i32;4];4] = vec1;
    let vec_two:[[i32;4];4] = vec2;

    // we need to store the sum
    let mut sum = 0;

    // we need to create the arrays to put the results into
    let mut result = [[0i32; 4]; 4];

    // loop through the two vectors
    for vone in 0..4
    {
        for vtwo in 0..4
        {
            for k in 0..4
            {
                sum = sum + vec1[[vone].k] * vec2[[k].vtwo];
            }
            result[[vec_one].vec_two] = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
   }

   return result;
}
```

I've also tried `result[vec_one][vec_two] = sum` but when I come to compile, it looks like there is a problem assigning to array.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Include the error message in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your error, I believe (at least one of them):

```
<anon>:15:34: 15:44 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&[&[i32; 4]; 4]`,
    found `&[[i32; 4]; 4]`
(expected &-ptr,
    found array of 4 elements) [E0308]
<anon>:15     let result = matrix_multiply(&array_one, &array_two);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem is, reference or dereference of arrays can't go on multiple levels of their nesting. This is because the memory layout of, say, `[&[i32; 4]; 4]` and `[[i32; 4]; 4]` is radically different, both in contents and in size - the former array consists of four pointers to other arrays (4*4=16/8*4=32 bytes total, depending on architecture of your machine), while the latter consists of four arrays laid out sequentially (4*4*4=64 bytes total). There is simply no way to go from `[[i32; 4]; 4]` to `&[&[i32; 4]; 4]` without rebuilding the outer array, which Rust won't ever do for you because it is too much magic.

You don't really need to use the inner reference; in fact, you probably don't even need to pass these arrays by reference at all: arrays of `Copy` types are `Copy` as well, so you can pass them by value. They are small enough to not cause any performance impact, and the compiler will probably optimize it automatically anyway:

```
fn main()  {
    // first create a couple of arrays - these will be used
    // for the vectors
    let line1: [i32; 4] = [4, 2, 3, 3];
    let line2: [i32; 4] = [3, 4, 5, 7];
    let line3: [i32; 4] = [2, 9, 6, 2];
    let line4: [i32; 4] = [5, 7, 2, 4];

    // create two holding arrays and assign
    let array_one = [line1, line3, line4, line2];
    let array_two = [line2, line1, line3, line4];

    // let's do the multiply
    let result = matrix_multiply(array_one, array_two);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}

fn matrix_multiply(vec1: [[i32; 4]; 4], vec2: [[i32; 4]; 4]) -> [[i32; 4]; 4] {
    // we need to create the arrays to put the results into
    let mut result = [[0i32; 4]; 4];

    // loop through the two vectors
    for vone in 0..4 {
        for vtwo in 0..4 {
            let mut sum = 0;
            for k in 0..4 {
                sum += vec1[vone][k] * vec2[k][vtwo];
            }
            result[vone][vtwo] = sum;
        }
   }

   result
}
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6ed08904da9803c81c00&version=stable))

I've also made your code more idiomatic according to the current community practices (braces positioning, spacing, etc.), and I've fixed the weird syntax for accessing arrays.

Comment: Thanks for such a well explained answer. I'm enjoying Rust :)

Answer (score 2):

If you write

```
let line1: [i32; 4] = [4, 2, 3, 3];
let line2: [i32; 4] = [3, 4, 5, 7];
let line3: [i32; 4] = [2, 9, 6, 2];
let line4: [i32; 4] = [5, 7, 2, 4];

// create two holding arrays and assign
let array_one = [line1, line3, line4, line2];
```

the type of `array_one` will be `[[i32;4];4]` because the line arrays are copied into `array_one`. Borrowing this via `&array_one` gives you something of type `&[[i32;4];4]` which is very different from `&[&[T; 4]; 4]` (what the function you try to call expects).

Option1 -- Create `[&[T; 4]; 4]`:

```
let array_one = [&line1, &line3, &line4, &line2];
some_function(&array_one);
...
fn some_function(matrix: &[&[i32;4];4]) {...}
```

Option2 -- Change the function sitnature:

```
let array_one = [line1, line3, line4, line2];
some_function(&array_one);
...
fn some_function(matrix: &[[i32;4];4]) {...}
```

If you're interested in dealing with multi-dimensional arrays of arbitrary sizes, perhaps you'll find my experimental [multiarray crate](https://crates.io/crates/multiarray) useful. It basically tries to offer types similar to `Box<[T]>`, `&[T]` and `&mut[T]` for two or more dimensions. Here's an untested example just to get an idea of what I was trying to do:

```
extern crate multiarray;

use multiarray::*;

fn main() {
    // the backing memory will be a dynamically allocated
    // linear array with 4 elements in row-major (C-style) order.
    let mut matrix = Array2D::new([2, 2], 0i32);
    matrix[[0,0]] = 1; matrix[[0,1]] = 2;
    matrix[[1,0]] = 3; matrix[[1,1]] = 4;
    let mut square = Array2D::new([2, 2], 0i32);
    // the borrow methods create reference-like proxies
    mat_product(matrix.borrow(), matrix.borrow(),
                square.borrow_mut());
}

fn mat_product(a: Array2DRef<i32>, b: Array2DRef<i32>,
               mut c: Array2DRefMut<i32>) {
    let rows = a.extents()[0]; // extent of 1st dimension
    let intr = a.extents()[1]; // extent of 2nd dimension
    let cols = b.extents()[1]; // extent of 2nd dimension
    assert!(intr == b.extents()[0]);
    assert!(rows == c.extents()[0]);
    assert!(cols == c.extents()[1]);
    for i in 0..rows {
        // the i-th row of a and c...
        let a_row_i = a.eliminated_dim(0, i);
        let mut c_row_i = c.reborrow_mut().eliminated_dim(0, i);
        for j in 0..cols {
            c_row_i[j] = dot_product(a_row_i, b.eliminated_dim(1, j));
            //                                ^^^j-th column of b^^^
        }
    }
}

fn dot_product(a: Array1DRef<i32>, b: Array1DRef<i32>) -> i32 {
    a.zip(b).fold(0, |acc,(&x,&y)| acc + x * y)
}
```